# Awk-compare 2 files using multiple columns and print lines from both files

Tags: bash, scripts, awk

So I have a two flat files that is in the format as follows

***File1.txt***

```
Customer1 12345 12346 12347 15646
Customer2 14444 14445
```

***File2.txt***

```
12345 aol.com
12347 gmail.com
12346 google.com
14444 yahoo.com
14445 outlook.com
15646 space.com
```

My Desire output would be:

```
Customer1 aol.com gmail.com google.com space.com
Customer2 yahoo.com outlook.com
```

I have came up with the following so far but it only seems to use column 2 from file 1, is there a was that I can expand this command out to include all of the columns in file 1?

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $2 in a {print $0, a[$2]}' OFS='\' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop over the fields `$2` onward in `File1.txt`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i = $i in a ? a[$i] : $i} 1' File2.txt File1.txt
Customer1 aol.com google.com gmail.com space.com
Customer2 yahoo.com outlook.com
```

The `$i = $i in a ? a[$i] : $i` may be simplified to `$i = a[$i]` if you're certain there will be a match, or if you want to replace non-matches with empty fields.